# pass delegate from one VC to another withOut using prepareForSegue

Tags: swift, delegates, key-value-observing

So i know how to make delegates and pass them using prepare for segue; however, I have a 3 Views (lets Call them A, B & C). View A connect to view B. View B has a button that leads to view C. In View C, there is a switch that toggles...

view connection: A->B->C

I want to make it so when the switch is toggled in View C, View A knows about it. without using KVO since the relationship is still 1-to-1

Comment: The same question has been asked many times for both Objective-C and Swift.  I don't see the point of pursuing an old war story over and over.

Comment: I decided to go with KVO; since it seems too much work to pass my delegate from VC-A to VC-B, then from VC-B to VC-C. and then use VC-C delegate to change data in VC-A.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a closure A->B->C, invoke the closure in View C when the switch is toggled and pass whatever info you want to the closure to inform View A.

Answer (score 0):

In VCA

```
let vcB = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCB") as VCB 
vcB.myDataB = "set my data"
navigationController?.pushViewController(vcB,animated: true)
```

In VCB create property

```
var myDataB : String!
```

Now, in VCB push your VC

```
let vcC = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VCC") as VCC 
    vcC.myDataC = myDataB
    navigationController?.pushViewController(vcC,animated: true)
```

Now, in VCC, create property,

```
var myDataC : String!
```

Now, your data which is in VCA is in VCC with property myDataC, you can use this data as per your need.